# How to combine two files into one with columns for each file's data?

Tags: bash, shell

I have two files:

file1 contains:

```
1
2
3
4
```

file2 contains:

```
John
Sam
George
Ken
```

I want to combine these files to create one file(file3)

```
1, John
2, Sam
3, George
4, Ken
```

My thought was to use nested loops and add the comma for each line,

```
for x in file1
do
echo "$x" >> file3
for y in file2
echo ",$y" >> file3
done
done
```

Is there a command I need to use? How do I get it to x and y to appear on one line for each entry in both files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use paste command

```
:|paste -d',' file1 - | paste -d' ' - file2
```

or

```
 :|paste -d', ' file1 - file2
```

Answer (score 2):

`paste` is the command you're looking for:

```
$ paste -d',' file1 file2
1,John
2,Sam
3,George
4,Ken
```

If you want the space after the comma, you can use this trick:

```
$ paste -d', ' file1 /dev/null file2
1, John
2, Sam
3, George
4, Ken
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one using awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$1;next}{print a[FNR] ".", $1}' file1 file2
1. John
2. Sam
3. George
4. Ken
```

Then again, if the `file1` is really numbers you could skip it and just:

```
$ awk '{print NR ",", $1}' file2
1, John
2, Sam
3, George
4, Ken
```